# Is there a way to use labeling to find a variable when 'is' is used in the rule?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, labeling

My predicate below is working as I want it to, when the number 3 occurs in a list the neighbors should be +-1 of each other, if that is the case it returns true. But when I try to use labeling to find a solution things fall apart.

So my question is if there is a way to use 'is' with labeling. I do not see another way of checking for exactly +-1 without using 'is'.

```
bigger(A,B):- A is B+1.
bigger(A,B):- B is A+1. 

neighCheck([_]).
neighCheck([A,B,C|T]):-
    (B = 3
    -> bigger(A,C)
    ; \+bigger(A,C)),
    neighCheck([C|T]).

/*returns true*/
:- neighCheck(1,3,2,3,1). 



:- N = 3,length(L,N),L ins 1..N,maplist(neighCheck, L),L=[_,3,_],labeling([],L).
```

Comment: Mixing [tag:clpfd] with `(->)/2` and the like does not work

Comment: Instead of `bigger/2`: `one_apart(X, Y) :- abs(X-Y) #= 1.`

Comment: `is` does not correspond to `labeling` . Put ```:- [library(clpfd)] .``` at the top of the file then use ``#=`` instead of ``is`` .

Comment: Thank for the help! Getting rid of the `->` and changing my bigger predicate to the one_apart works like a charm.